# Coefficient estimates for model with more than one categorical explanatory variable

Tags: r, statistics, contrast

I am currently doing a meta-analysis looking at the effects of logging in tropical forests.

As part of this I have been testing hypotheses about whether the effects vary by region and method of logging used.

I am doing all of this using the **metafor** package in R.

My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(Method = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("Conventional", "RIL"), class = "factor"), MU = c(192.96, 
252.41, 235.6, 258, 258, 399, 313, 409.8, 420.4, 333.47, 327.54, 
256, 228.1, 547.1, 453.3873094, 427.495, 346.8, 330.833333333333, 
343.3, 221.5, 194.8, 51.1, 276), SSU = c(3, 3, 30, 3, 3, 2, 5, 
17, 10, 4, 4, 4, 9, 15, 35, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 10), ML = c(157.03, 
171.97, 219.5, 198, 148, 191, 204, 315.3647059, 386.22, 135.8, 
211.78, 183.8, 159.9, 230.8, 97.00798294, 218.31, 279.933333333333, 
261.4, 249.733333333333, 118.6, 42.9, 18.7, 128.4), SSL = c(3, 
3, 10, 3, 3, 10, 5, 17, 10, 4, 4, 4, 9, 10, 131, 45, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 10), Region = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("Africa", "Americas", "Asia & Oceania"), class = "factor"), 
SDU = c(7.69030558560582, 12.1243556529821, 74.4902678207026, 
30, 30, 145, 107.33126291999, 64.9, 92.95, 40.73364703, 54.0371067, 
53.6, 98.1, 193.8, 16.13693527, 109.3250955, 28.21329474, 
30.91865671942, 32.220024829289, 37.065887281974, 96.4752299815865, 
37.4122974434878, 91.706052144883), SDL = c(8.46972844901181, 
7.81154914213564, 53.1262646908288, 18, 10, 324.8738217, 
84.970583144992, 44.90907399, 109.0794186, 20.75198304, 18.6400617, 
11.6, 88.2, 104.2, 4.008416039, 185.9464001, 29.85034897, 
28.7292533839639, 15.297494348204, 37.7587076050015, 32.5625551822949, 
7.44781847254617, 126.174878640718)), .Names = c("Method", 
"MU", "SSU", "ML", "SSL", "Region", "SDU", "SDL"), row.names = c(NA, 
23L), class = "data.frame")
```

I then used this to calculate effect sizes and associated SEs for each site I have data for, like this:

```
require("metafor")
ROM <- escalc(data=AGB, measure="ROM", m2i=MU, sd2i=SDU,
              n2i=SSU, m1i=ML, sd1i=SDL, n1i=SSL, append=TRUE)
```

My problem is that I don't know how to interpret the treatment contrasts from a model with two categorical predictors.

My 'best' model (the one with lowest AIC) looks like this:

```
ROM.ma1 <- rma(yi,vi,mods=~Method+Region,method="ML",data=ROM)
```

using a random effects model.

```
summary(ROM.ma1)
```

gives us this:

```
Mixed-Effects Model (k = 23; tau^2 estimator: ML)

  logLik  deviance       AIC       BIC  
 -4.2852   65.8950   18.5705   24.2479  

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.0634 (SE = 0.0241)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.2519
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 90.58%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   10.62

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 19) = 616.2226, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2,3,4): 
QM(df = 3) = 17.0683, p-val = 0.0007

Model Results:

                      estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb   ci.ub   
intrcpt                -0.4392  0.3150  -1.3944  0.1632  -1.0566  0.1781   
MethodRIL               0.3544  0.1513   2.3420  0.0192   0.0578  0.6510  *
RegionAmericas          0.1027  0.3201   0.3208  0.7484  -0.5247  0.7301   
RegionAsia & Oceania   -0.3487  0.3068  -1.1365  0.2557  -0.9500  0.2526   

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Now I understand that the intercept is a combination of the first levels of the factors `Method` and `Region`.

What I would like to be able to do is calculate coefficient estimates for each of these groups along with their confidence intervals so I can plot the results of this test.

Is there a way in which I could do this?

I have asked a number of colleagues and none of them have given me a useful response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate coefficient estimates for each of these groups". You want an estimate of the RegionAfrica coefficient? But there is no such coefficient in your model.

Comment: Not sure I get your point. Looking at my data I have only one measurement in Africa, for which Method=Conventional. I guess I could be overfitting my data, considering that I should have at least 3 datapoints for each parameter I attempt to estimate. But my model does include an estimate for Africa - that is what the intercept is in this case.

Comment: So, if the intercept is what you need, what is your question? However, the intercept and the coefficient `RegionAmericas` clearly represent different things.

Comment: Lets start again. The intercept represents a combination of the first two levels of the factors Method and Region. In this case Conventional+Africa. All other contrasts are differences from that estimate. Thus the estimates represent Conventional+Africa, RIL+Africa, Conventional+Americas, Conventional+Asia & Oceania. What I wanted to know was whether it was possible to get coefficient estimates for: Conventional, RIL, Africa, Americas, Asia & Oceania. In the context of my question I think I am trying to overfit the data,but I'm interested whether it's technically possible for future reference.

Comment: @Phil_Martin Please tell us exactly, what the desired coefficients are supposed to represent in the model. But I suspect the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Right. My model looks at the impacts of logging in different regions with different harvesting methods. I have good reasons to suspect differences in impacts between regions and with different methods. However, I don't want to do separate individual meta-analyses to test these hypotheses as excluding ohe explanatory variable might lead to misleading results. So really I wanted to get mean estimates for the different levels of the factors Method(levels="Conventional","RIL") and Regions(levels="Africa","Americas","Asia & Oceania"). Does that help?

Comment: Difference to what? To calculate differences you need something to compare against. Could you possibly want pair-wise comparisons (post-hoc tests)?

Comment: @Roland Maybe, but I not aware of how you would do post-hoc tests with the results generated by metafor.

Comment: I am not familar with that package. If you were using lme4, I'd suggest package multcomp.

Comment: Ok. How would you do it using multcomp?

Comment: Read `?multcomp::glht` (and search the web including stats.stackexchange.com).